I get no response from Paystack when I trigger the subscription endpoint
I am not getting a response from Paystack when I hit their subscriptions endpoint, I need the subscription code and status from the response for my database, and I have already created plans in the paystack dashboard.
I tried using the https://api.paystack.co/transaction/initialize, with should contian email, amount and plan code I got not response also tried the https://api.paystack.co/subscriptions with the customer code and plan code I got no response for that as well can anyone help?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
